# How to handle pop-up or alert in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

whenever I'm running my code, I'm getting pop-up.
how to cancel that pop-up for the website : https://www.goibibo.com/

whenever I'm running my code, I'm getting pop-up.
how to cancel that pop-up for the website : https://www.goibibo.com/

```
package basic;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;


public class goibibo {
    private static WebDriver driver = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='gosuggest_inputSrc']"))).sendKeys("A");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        List<WebElement> myList = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='dib marginL10 pad0 textOverflow width90']/div/span")));
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++)
        {
                System.out.println(myList.get(i).getText());
                if (myList.get(i).getText().equals("Ahmedabad"))
                {
                    myList.get(i).click();
                    break;
                }
            }
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gosuggest_inputDest\"]"))).sendKeys("Mum");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        List<WebElement> Dept = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@class='dib marginL10 pad0 textOverflow width90']/div/span")));
        for (int j = 0; j < Dept.size(); j++)
        {
                System.out.println(Dept.get(j).getText());
                if (Dept.get(j).getText().equals("Mumbai"))
                {
                    Dept.get(j).click();
                    break;
                }
        }
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();
    }

}


no such alert
```

Comment: I don't see any alert on the webpage. Can you post screen of the alert? What's the symptom? Any expecption?

Comment: @sharful thats not Alert thats just html frame

Comment: @Dhru'soni  in that case then how can we cancel that in the same code.

Comment: @sharful first switch to your iframe you will get xpath of close icon and than click on it. it will close that popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First that's not popup that's an Iframe.

you can get more information from this link how to handle [iframe](https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html) in selenium

first you need to swich to the iframe.

for that you need to write below code after your `Thread.sleep(3000);` find the iframe name from your html source.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("notification-frame-~2514428c7");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@class='wewidgeticon we_close']")).click();
```

By using this you can close your html popup.

Comment: this works man thanks.  driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); then i have to use this right ?

Comment: @sharful driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); in this case focus will move to parent frame of all nested frames. for Example, I have i1,i2,i3 frames are there which are nested frames. in this case, if I use default content() when focus at i3, it moves to the i1 frame. but from my side best way to use driver.switchTo().frame("notification-frame-~2514428c7");

Answer (score 0):

as i can see this is the alert you are getting right

[image]

so you can do one thing you can write a code for an alert, if an alert is visible then press the close button surrounded by try catch so you can easily get rid of the alert when ever the alert will come it will closed ASAP and you execution will disturbed but you need to use the wait for the main elements like for from and to textfields like if you give them less wait and if the pop up takes to much time to close then test case will fail and one more thing the popup comes only one time in an one session when we are passing the source and to values

let us know if you need any more help

Comment: thats not popup thats iframe. user need to swith to the iframe.

Comment: but it's randomly comes how do we switch in between

Comment: it's not come randomly after waiting for website for 3 or 4 second that popup will comes.

Comment: i din't received popup for chrome browser even because that's website is updated frequently, i receved popup in my firefox browser as i did not removed some local  website cache from my firfox.

Answer (score 0):

This is `iframe` which stopping you to access the element.Use `webdriverwait` and `switch` to `iframe` first and then access the element.Try the below code.

```
driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name ,'notification-frame-')]")));
WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//i[contains(@class ,'wewidgeticon')]")));
element.click();
```

Comment: can you let me know how to click on the "departure" and "return"  and select the desired dates  of the choice in the same code ?